# How to use netty to run a websocket server and not process other types HTTP requests (like GET and POST).

Tags: websocket, netty

I'm using Netty 4.1.1 to run a websocket server.  Only want to process websocket and not process other types HTTP requests (like GET and POST).

In Netty API for WebSocketServerProtocolHandler,  it says:

"This handler does all the heavy lifting for you to run a websocket server. It takes care of websocket handshaking as well as processing of control frames (Close, Ping, Pong). Text and Binary data frames are passed to the next handler in the pipeline (implemented by you) for processing. See **io.netty.example.http.websocketx.html5.WebSocketServer** for usage. The implementation of this handler assumes that you just want to run a websocket server and not process other types HTTP requests (like GET and POST)."

But I can't find io.netty.example.http.websocketx.html5.WebSocketServer.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the doc is outdated.

You can refer `io.netty.example.http.websocketx.server.WebSocketServer`.

If you want to check `io.netty.example.http.websocketx.html5.WebSocketServer`, you can checkout commit `2704efc`.

Comment: louxiu, thanks. io.netty.example.http.websocketx.server.WebSocketServer support http and websocket. But I only want to support websocket.  I will find io.netty.example.http.websocketx.html5.WebSocketServer as you said.